# How to create own dataset in c++ pyTorch

Tags: c++, pytorch

I'm try to do some machine learning with pyTorch C++. I got own dataset in .csv files and after loading them I receive eg. [N,M] 2D std::vector with N samples and M features and [N,] 1D std::vector with N labels.

My question is, what should I do to create proper dataset to use torch::data::make_data_loader method (or other) and learn my NN.

Thanks in advance!